# Dereferencing the fields of a structure in C

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, dereference

I have:

```
typedef struct table {

int size;

} Table;
```

So I have a parameter for a method as:

```
Table **table
```

But when I do:

```
table->size = 5;
```

OR:

```
*table->size = 5;
```

It doesn't work and my flags is giving me the error: request for member 'size' in something not a structure or union

Please help.

Comment: No I need Table **table as my argument parameters for this project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid all that weird indirection, it's easier to use a local variable and go:

```
void myfunc(Table ** my_table) {
    Table * ptable = *my_table;
    ptable->size = 5;

    /*  etc  */
}
```

but as others have pointed out, `(*table)->size = 5` and the like will do the same thing.

If you need to modify what's being pointed to, then:

```
void myfunc(Table ** my_table) {
    Table * ptable = malloc(sizeof(*ptable));

    /*  Do stuff with new table, then update argument  */

    *my_table = ptable;
}
```

Here's an example of the latter:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct table {
    int size;
} Table;

int create_table(Table ** table, int size) {
    Table * new_table = malloc(sizeof(*new_table));
    if ( new_table == NULL ) {
        return -1;
    }

    new_table->size = size;

    *table = new_table;
    return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    Table * my_table;

    if ( create_table(&my_table, 5) == -1 ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't allocate memory for new table.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("New table size is %d\n", my_table->size);

    free(my_table);

    return 0;
}
```

You *could*, of course, just have `create_table()` return a `Table *` to the newly created table, but in your case, that function has been declared as returning `int`. Could be for any number of reasons, but in the above I've just assumed it's to return an error code. As we know, a function in C can only return one value, so if it's returning an `int` it can't return a `Table *` as well, so the only way to get that new pointer is to modify an argument, and if you want to modify a `Table *`, you have to pass the address of that `Table *`, so your function must accept a `Table **`.

Comment: Ok the Table **table parameter is passed in as an argument to create a table.

Comment: Like: int create_table(Table **table, int size, etc...) {

Comment: So in this case, why does table have a double pointer? Isn't it useless?

Comment: Presumably you are passing the address of a pointer to it, I'll knock up a quick example.

Comment: @user2817240: Added an example and an explanation to show why this type of thing is not useless.

Comment: Ok now I understand, thanks for your reply. Also lastly, when you are allocating space for the Table structure, couldn't you do: Table *new_table = malloc(sizeof(Table)); ?

Comment: Yes, the method returns an error if you can't create the table

Comment: @user2817240: You certainly could do the `malloc()` like that, yes, but doing it the way I showed is better, since it automatically determines the correct type, so if you ever change the type of `new_table` (admittedly pretty unlikely in this particular case, unless you change the name of your struct) you don't have to change the operand to `sizeof`.

Comment: This just came up, couldn't you declare in main Table my_table and send the address of that (so it would be: create_table(&my_table, size) to the create table function and it would have the address that way and is able to modify the table?

Comment: Seems like a pointer to the table, and then sending the address of that pointer to another method.

Comment: seems a little redundant

Comment: Yes, you absolutely could do that, and in a problem as simple as this, you probably should. There are times when you'd want to create things dynamically, though (when making a linked list, for instance), and this would be how you'd do it.

Answer (score 2):

The dereference operator (`*`) has a lower priority, so this:

```
*table->size
```

is evaluated as:

```
*(table->size)
```

Since `table` is a pointer to a pointer, and pointers can't have members, you get an error. What you need is:

```
(*table)->size = 5;
```

Now, `*table` is evaluated first, yielding a pointer to a `Table`. `->` is then able to be applied to it.

Unrelated:

I noticed that you use different identifiers for the struct name and for its typedef. This isn't necessary. You can just use:

```
typedef struct Table {
    int size;
} Table;
```

Answer (score 0):

if using `table_t **mytable`
do `(*mytable)->size = 5;`

if using `table_t *mytable`
do `mytable->size = 5;`

```
typedef struct /* table */ {
    int size;
} table_t;  //conventional naming

int main() {
    table_t *mytable = malloc((sizeof *mytable)); //avoid "Access Violation", by allocating memory
    mytable->size = 5; //set size to '5'
    return 0; //conventional return
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question :-/ Function parameters that need to get a `Table*` by reference, will need to use `Table**` (for any type `foo`, if you need to pass by reference you need to use `foo*`.) This is what the question was about.

Comment: then all he has to do is add an extra '*'

Comment: Then you get `table_t **mytable` and you're back to the original problem without having answered anything :-P

Comment: And change all the other lines in `main()` except `return 0;`.

Comment: Btw, `_t` is a reserved suffix on some operating systems (like Mac OS X and Linux, and generally on everything that tries to support POSIX) and shouldn't be used unless you know you're not on those systems.

Comment: The first line in your new answer, the OP already said that he tried that, and it didn't work, and he's correct.